# how to WhereIn a whereday of array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
array:23 [▼
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
      2 => 3
      3 => 4
      4 => 5
      5 => 8
      6 => 9
      7 => 10
      8 => 11
      9 => 12
      10 => 15
      11 => 16
      12 => 17
      13 => 18
      14 => 19
      15 => 22
      16 => 23
      17 => 24
      18 => 25
      19 => 26
      20 => 29
      21 => 30
      22 => 31
    ]
```

this is a array of working days apart from Sunday and Saturday  and i have a table of months data and i need a Laravel where condition for comparing all data with whe

```
->whereYear('Clock_Day',$yearofdata)
->whereMonth('Clock_Day',$monthofdata)
->whereIn('Clock_Day','=',$workdays) //here can i use something like whereIn->whereday---for comparing all array values and get as per the data
```

Comment: Did you try with `->whereIn('Clock_Day',$workdays)` ?

Comment: @user2486 yeah not working

Comment: do you really want to compare as `all date` should exit ?  and not `any one` ?

Comment: i just want to get all data which gets compared with array of values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `whereDayIn()` or similar method, but you can do this:

```
->whereYear('Clock_Day', $yearofdata)
->whereMonth('Clock_Day', $monthofdata)
->where(function($q) use($workdays) {
    foreach ($workdays as $day) {
        $q->whereDay('Clock_Day', '=', $day, 'or');
    }
})
```

Comment: Just curious `->whereIn('Clock_Day',$workdays)` will this not work ?

Answer (score 2):

If `Clock_Day` is a field in your table, you will need to extract the date part you are comparing for each piece (Year, Month, Day). You could possibly use whereIn with DB::raw:

```
->where(DB::raw('YEAR("Clock_Day")'),$yearofdata)
->where(DB::raw('MONTH("Clock_Day")'),$monthofdata)
->whereIn(DB::raw('DAYOFMONTH("Clock_Day")'),$workdays)
```

You would only use whereYear or whereMonth to compare those values against fields in your table called 'year' and 'month', but since you want to use the same 'Clock_Day' field for all comparisons you need to extract the relevant data for each part.